# Ms Access Send Email with Report as Attachment

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, report, attachment

Using VBA code builder in MS Access, I have been able to write code that opens Outlook and send me an email with the click of a button.  I am having problems with adding an attachment. Most code I have found adds files outside the MS Database as an attachment, I would like to add a report created in my database as an attachment.

```
Private Sub EmailReport_Click()
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

'Email the results of the report generated
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oEmail.To = "myemailaddress@email.com"
oEmail.Subject = "Training Roster"
oEmail.Body = "Roster Information"

With oEmail
    .Send
    MsgBox "Email Sent"
End With
```

I have been looking into a command similar to

```
oEmail.Attachments.Add Me.
```

..But, I cannot find the correct combination for adding my report.
Thanks!!

Comment: Export your report externally in a .PDF and then add as attachments referencing full file path.

Comment: I don't think this will work for me.  There will be multiple users of this database and I cannot anticipate the full path on multiple work stations.

Comment: Use the database's current location: `Application.CurrentProject.Path &"\" & "filename.pdf"` so PDF is saved wherever database is located.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned, export your report into an external file such as .pdf in order to attach to your outgoing email. Remember a report is an internal Access object and not readily in a file format for email. With [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx), you can dynamically create the pdf on the fly date-stamped and in [same location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191878.aspx) as the database for a generalizeable solution for all your users.

```
Private Sub EmailReport_Click()
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fileName As string, todayDate As String    

'Export report in same folder as db with date stamp
todayDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
fileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\ReportName_" & todayDate & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, fileName, False

'Email the results of the report generated
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With oEmail
    .Recipients.Add "myemailaddress@email.com"
    .Subject = "Training Roster"
    .Body = "Roster Information"
    .Attachments.Add fileName
    .Send        
End With

MsgBox "Email successfully sent!", vbInformation, "EMAIL STATUS"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can export your report as PDF by email with this:

```
DoCmd.SendObject(ObjectType, ObjectName, OutputFormat, To, Cc, Bcc,Subject, MessageText, EditMessage, TemplateFile)
```

Comment: You cand see more in this web: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/ff197046.aspx

Answer (score -1):

With using `DoCmd.SendObject` you need to update Outlook Programmatic Access to turn off warnings about auto sending emails. In my case, administrator of domain enabled this options to change. More information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-email-address-information-or-sending-email-on-my-behalf-86cc5ece-379e-45e3-b8eb-3fefba09946b?NS=MSACCESS&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZAC160&HelpId=olmain11.chm553714172&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).